# magento product link goes blank after searching product

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, php-5.4, indexing

I am using Luxury theme and I am getting issue regarding search.

See my video about the error: https://www.screencast.com/t/sCcPQFeC

Whenever we search the product by name and click on product detail page it’s showing blank page but when I open same product through main navigation then it’s working fine.

http://usatileandmarble.net/

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong in the code. When you look in the source you will see the rendering is halted just after

```
<section id="maincontent" >
```

What can you do to pinpoint the problem? A couple of things.

- Enable developer mode (allways a good idea when developing)
- Enable logging and check the log files
- Enable error reporting in your /index.php
- Check server log files (apache/nginx)

This should give you enough information to resolve the actual issue. You can allways add the error data if you need more assistance.